# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream for big requests with node and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

Hello I have a node application, which works with nginx as a reverse proxy, and if i want to access to the session 99 in my application, which is rather big, i have these errors in nginx :

```
2017/07/03 13:09:56 [warn] 199#199: *118 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/5/00/0000000005 while reading upstream, request: "GET /api/organisme_formation/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/api/organisme_formation/",
2017/07/03 13:10:03 [warn] 199#199: *122 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/6/00/0000000006 while reading upstream, client: 92.154.49.177, 
2017/07/03 13:10:09 [error] 199#199: *118 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, request: "GET /api/session?eq=id.99 HTTP/1.1",
```

In the web browser i have a 502 bad gateway :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

Response headers :

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:576
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 03 Jul 2017 14:35:11 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.10
```

Here is my nginx configuration file :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    client_max_body_size 0m;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I tried alose this configuration :

```
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
client_max_body_size 0m;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
```

But it doesnt work neither.

I checked my back-end with pm2 and i have this error :

```
PM2        | App [index] with id [0] and pid [258], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGKILL]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:index id:0
PM2        | App name:index id:0 online
```